# solving ODE with power law solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have this equation:

$$ 3R' ^2  =-2R \frac{d^2R}{dt^2}$$

How can I show that If

$$R=R_0 t^\alpha $$

then

$$\alpha = 2/5$$

Comment: If $R(t)=R_0t^\alpha$, then $-2R(t)R''(t)=-2\alpha (\alpha -1)R_0^2t^{2\alpha -2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R(t)=R_0t^\alpha$, then

$$3R'^2(t)=3\alpha^2R_0^2t^{2\alpha-2} \tag 1$$

and

$$-2R(t)R''(t)=-2\alpha (\alpha -1)R_0^2t^{2\alpha -2} \tag 2$$

Now equate the right-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: I see, if I put into wolfram I Get alpha = 2/5

Comment: Even easier;  for $\alpha\ne 0$, note that $$-2\alpha(\alpha -1)=3\alpha^2\implies 2-2\alpha=3\alpha$$

Comment: I see, thanks! Could you take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699005/solving-ode-for-cylindrical-and-planar-cases  it is very related question but for cylindrical and planar. Not sure how to approach since there are move variables that just R

Answer (score 2):

If $R=R_0t^{\alpha}$ then $R'=\alpha R_0t^{\alpha-1}$ and $R''=\alpha(\alpha-1) R_0t^{\alpha-2}$. So your equation becomes: $$3\alpha^2R_0^2t^{2\alpha-2}=-2R_0t^{\alpha}\times\alpha(\alpha-1) R_0t^{\alpha-2}=-2\alpha(\alpha-1)R_0^2t^{2\alpha-2}$$ It implies that $3\alpha^2=-2\alpha(\alpha-1)$ so...